# MYSQL subtract value if input differs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, sql-update

I have a text area (txt_desCription) on a form that is used to calculate a score. The score is weighted as follows:
If the input in the text area is smaller than 75 words, 5 points is added to a the col_score column(TINYINT(1) in the tbl_score table of the database.
If the input in the text area is greater than 75 words, 10 points is added to a the col_score(TINYINT(1) column in the tbl_score table of the database.
An onblur event calls the jquery script that 'counts' the words and then sends it to the add_score.php page that handles the update event. Code below:

```
if (isset($_POST["txt_desCription"]));  {  
    $sessionscore = $_POST["txt_desCription"]; // ◄■■ PARAMETER FROM AJAX.  
    if ($sessionscore <= 75) {
        $descscore = 5;
    } else if ($sessionscore >= 75) {       
        $descscore = 10;                
    }
    $updatesql=sprintf("UPDATE tmp_score 
                            SET col_score=col_score+%s 
                        WHERE sessionid = %s",
                    GetSQLValueString($descscore, "int"),
                    GetSQLValueString($_SESSION['sessionid'], "text")
                    );                 
    $result=mysql_query($updatesql) or die(mysql_error());          

}
```

It works perfectly well, but what I cannot figure out is **how to update the score if the user goes back and make changes to the text in the text area?**

With other Words, what if the user changes their mind about the answer and goes back and change their answer to a shorter or longer one? Meaning the value will change from 5 to 10 or vise versa.

Please help. My hair is thinning by the second :-)

Comment: The way you are doing it now, you can't: You don't keep track of the result, you just add it so sending in the same form multiple times would lead to multiple increments. You should track the scores for specific questions in a different table so that you can re-calculate the real total score at any time.

Comment: Basically you are going to have to write a lot more code to keep track of the situation you are talking about.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you need to use onchange jquery event and send ajax request every time user change the value. You ajax request will look something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(document).on("change","#textareaId",function(){
  $.ajax({type: "POST",
    url: 'yourUrl', //Ajax request url here 
   data:{}, // data to update here
    success: function(data) {
       //do something with response here 
     }
   });
});

});
```

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: Thanks Sanposh. You steered met in the right direction. I added a onfocus event and a beforesend function in the ajac update statement to check if the values have change. It works  now.

Comment: I am glad, it did help you out, even though I got two negative vote.

Comment: Strange, I can definitely tell you that you advice did help and it solved my problem. As soon as my ranking is up I will give you a positive vote.